# What is the use of @HystrixCommand annotation without a fallback method?

Tags: spring, hystrix

I have following code in my project

```
@HystrixCommand(groupKey = "AddressRepository", commandKey = 
"getAddressById", threadPoolKey = "addressSearchPool")
public List<Address> getAddressById(String id)
  throws MyCustomException, HystrixRuntimeException {

     try (Connection con = sql2o.open()) {
         return // some logic....

     } catch (Sql2oException e) {
        throw new MyCustomException();
     } 
}
```

As you can see @HystrixCommand does not define any fallbackMethod. I am wondering what purpose HystrixCommand is serving here.

What is the use case of using HystrixCommand when no fallback is defined?

Code is part of a Spring application.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that returning default response in case of failure is not only one of hystrix features.

> Stop cascading failures. Fallbacks and graceful degradation. Fail fast
>   and rapid recovery.

1) If you will not override `getFallback` method default implementation will be used:

```
  protected R getFallback() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No fallback available.");
    }
```

Despite the fact that no graceful response returned ( only exception thrown ) [circuit breaker pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) and fail fast principle will still work.

2) In fallback method you will usually return empty object or collection. There might be some cases when you don't want to return empty objects in case of failure, but you want to show that your service doesn't work and return some 5xx http status code and appropriate message.